# Why does basicReject does not work with Apache Qpid?

Tags: spring, kotlin, rabbitmq, amqp, qpid

I'm using `qpid-broker` for integration testing my `spring-boot-start-amqp` application which uses `basicGet` (autoAck=false), `basicAck` and `basicReject` for handling the messages. `basicReject` (with requeue=false) works fine with my external `rabbitmq` instance but doesn't work with the `qpid-broker`.

I have tested my code with an external RabbitMQ instance where everything works fine but with the embedded Apache Qpid server the test fails because `basicReject` is not working properly.

Getting the message and rejecting it:

```
rabbitTemplate.execute {
    val response = it.basicGet(config.queueName, false)
    it.basicReject(response.envelope.deliveryTag, false)
}
```

Check if the message is still in the queue:

```
rabbitTemplate.execute {
    val response = it.basicGet(config.queueName, false)
    Assertions.assertThat(response).isNull()
}
```

My Qpid config:

```
{
  "name": "EmbeddedBroker",
  "modelVersion": "7.0",
  "authenticationproviders": [
    {
      "name": "password",
      "type": "Plain",
      "secureOnlyMechanisms": [],
      "users": [
        {
          "name": "guest",
          "password": "guest",
          "type": "managed"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ports": [
    {
      "name": "AMQP",
      "port": "${qpid.amqp_port}",
      "protocols": [ "AMQP_0_9_1" ],
      "authenticationProvider": "password",
      "virtualhostaliases": [
        {
          "name": "defaultAlias",
          "type": "defaultAlias"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "virtualhostnodes": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "defaultVirtualHostNode": "true",
      "type": "Memory",
      "virtualHostInitialConfiguration": "{\"type\": \"Memory\" }"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why does `basicReject` work fine with my RabbitMQ instance but doesn't work properly with the Apache Qpid embedded broker?

Edit: My solution was to move away from qpid and use a [RabbitMQ Testcontainer](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/rabbitmq/).