# Message requeued after AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException with Qpid

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp, qpid

I am using rabbitMQ for production and in-memory Qpid for integration testing in my Spring boot app. But I encountered a problem when AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException is thrown - Qpid requeues the message instead of discarding it. With rabbitMQ it is working fine.

I am using gradle with dependencies (used older version but after upgrade problem still persists):

```
    testCompile("org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker-core:7.1.5")
    testCompile("org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker-plugins-memory-store:7.1.5")
    testCompile("org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker-plugins-amqp-0-8-protocol:7.1.5"):
```

My qpid config:

```
{
  "name": "Embedded Broker",
  "modelVersion": "6.0", //not working for 7.0 either
  "authenticationproviders" : [ {
    "name": "password",
    "type": "Plain",
    "secureOnlyMechanisms": [],
    "users": [{"name": "xxx", "password": "xxx", "type": "managed"}]
  } ],
  "ports" : [  {
    "name" : "AMQP",
    "port" : "5672",
    "protocols": [ "AMQP_0_9_1" ],
    "authenticationProvider" : "password",
    "virtualhostaliases" : [ {
      "name" : "nameAlias",
      "type" : "nameAlias"
    }, {
      "name" : "defaultAlias",
      "type" : "defaultAlias"
    }, {
      "name" : "hostnameAlias",
      "type" : "hostnameAlias"
    } ]
  }],
  "virtualhostnodes" : [ {
    "name" : "default",
    "type" : "Memory",
    "defaultVirtualHostNode" : "true",
    "virtualHostInitialConfiguration" : "{\"type\": \"Memory\"}"
  }]
}
```

Issue seems similar to: [Why does basicReject does not work with Apache Qpid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873395/why-does-basicreject-does-not-work-with-apache-qpid)
Is this a known problem?